# JS error: stringtime.match is not a function? while trying to transform duration from "2h 3min" string to numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote this code and thought that it was successful. However, when I ran it in some tests, I got a result "stringtime.match is not a function".

I'm trying to write the code in which I create a turnHoursToMinutes() function that receives an array as parameter, and - replaces the duration info of each of the movies for its equivalent in minutes. I will also need to return a new array with all the info about movies, meaning, I shouldn't modify the original array.

```
let movies = [
  {
    title: 'The Shawshank Redemption',
    year: '1994',
    director: 'Frank Darabont',
    duration: '2h 22min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.3'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather',
    year: '1972',
    director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
    duration: '2h 55min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.2'
  },
  {
    title: 'The Godfather: Part II',
    year: '1974',
    director: 'Francis Ford Coppola',
    duration: '3h 22min',
    genre: ['Crime', 'Drama'],
    rate: '9.0'
  }
]

function turnHoursToMinutes(minutesArr) {
  let durationArr = minutesArr.map(currentItem => {
    let stringtime = currentItem.duration;
    let strnumbers = stringtime.match(/\d+/g);
    let numbers = strnumbers.map(Number);
    let minutes = 0;
    if (stringtime.includes("h") && stringtime.includes("min")) {
      minutes = (numbers[0] * 60) + numbers[1];
    } else if (stringtime.includes("h")) {
      minutes = numbers[0] * 60;
    } else if (stringtime.includes("min")) {
      minutes = numbers[1];
    } 
    currentItem.duration = minutes;
    return {...currentItem};
  });

  return durationArr;

}
console.log(turnHoursToMinutes(movies));
```

I looked online for solutions and tried to apply some suggestions to my code but I couldn't get it to work :( Also, I thought I return a new array but I still got an error saying that I didn't return a new array...

I made sure that stringtime is a string like one solution said but I still can't get it working. Please help!

Comment: Your code works fine for me when I run it unchanged in Node.

Comment: Of course if you pass it an array with one or more objects with no `duration` property or where `duration` is not a string, it won't work.

Comment: I wrapped the code after `let stringtime = currentItem.duration` into a condition: `if (typeof stringtime === "string" || stringtime !== null || stringtime !== "")` but it's still not working.

Comment: You should update the question with that version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), as it says:

#### The match() method retrieves the result of matching a string against a regular expression.

So if you pass something that it is not a string or simply you dont put an object with the property `duration` , it will throw you an error.

You must check if `let stringtime = currentItem.duration;` is null or not.

Comment: I wrapped the code after `let stringtime = currentItem.duration` into a condition: `if (typeof stringtime === "string" || stringtime !== null || stringtime !== "") ` but it's still not working.

Comment: You could check it like this ```if (!currentItem.duration) console.log('If thre is no duration property, it enters here')```

Comment: Did my comment help you?